# Show hide multiple tables

Tags: javascript, html

I was wondering if someone could help me out with a command;

If have the following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function show_table(id){
  document.getElementById('table1').style.display='none';
  document.getElementById('table2').style.display='none';
  document.getElementById('table3').style.display='none';
  document.getElementById('table4').style.display='none';
  document.getElementById('table6').style.display='none';
  document.getElementById('table'+id).style.display='block';
}
</script>
```

And it shows the tables just fine that I have, but now I want to use a command to open two tables at the same time, so with one click on the below reference link;

```
<a href="#" onclick="show_table(6)">Table6</a>
```

Is it possible to use it with a double onclick="" command? I would like to open as example table(6) and table(2). What should I write? By the way I can only use javascript, no PHP.

I tried something like this, but is does not do the job

```
<a href="#" onclick="show_table(6),show_table(2)">Table6 and Table2</a>
```

Comment: You can create two separate functions.

Comment: what is the relation between the 2 table ids that needs to be open? Is it random?

Comment: If you were going to use that way anyways (2 function calls), you need to separate them with a `;`, not a `,`

Comment: Remember to [up vote and accept](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12462485/144665).

Answer (score 2):

Try this version, which can take a number or an array:

```
function show_table(id) {
    var ix;

    for (ix = 1;  ix <= 6;  ++ix) {
        document.getElementById('table' + ix).style.display='none';
    }
    if (typeof id === "number") {
        document.getElementById('table'+id).style.display='block';
    } else if (id && id.length) {
        for (ix = 0;  ix < id.length;  ++ix) {
            document.getElementById('table'+ix).style.display='block';
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can say show_table([1, 2]) instead of just show_table(1).

Comment: Why bother doing that when you can just enforce an array? Even if the array would hold a single value?

Comment: Because it's wasteful.  Creating arrays costs resources and the array will end up in the garbage collector.  One of the best things about JavaScript is its type flexibility.  You could even make ids a string and check for that.

Comment: Seriously? A single empty array is wasteful? That's ridiculous. Creating arrays cost resources, creating a variable costs resources, calling methods costs resources, everything does. I feel like using an array, which MAY not be necessary, is more useful than the "performance issues" posed by having to loop twice when necessary and doing extra checking.

Comment: @anonymousdownvotingislame any function would throw errors if given the wrong type of input.

Comment: @ianpgall: The array ISN'T necessary.  My code shows that it isn't.  If you're not using JavaScript's type system effectively, you should learn to.  There are a lot of benefits to it.  I resisted at first, too, having been a C++ and C# guy first.

Comment: @anonymousdownvoting, the OP did not ask for a perfectly safe function.  Your downvote is unreasonable.

Comment: @AresAvatar I never said an array is necessary. You've clearly provided a different solution without enforcing arrays which is fine. Essentially all you're doing is providing function overloading in one function. The "overhead" of an array is so incredibly miniscule that I can't believe anyone would even consider that a factor for choosing a solution to this. Javascript arrays are smart - they don't need to be declared with a size, so they only take up as much room as they hold. I'd much rather enforce a type and reduce code, than produce all this extra checking for something so simple...

Comment: I've already made my points and don't intend to repeat myself.  I still suggest you read up on how to write solid, performant, flexible JS code.  I'll leave it at that.

Comment: @ianpgall That is simply not true. Checking inputs for validity before running them is best practice coding. My [answer for example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12411837/144665) confirms the existence of DOM elements before attempting to access their properties.

Comment: @anonymous, some checking is excessive.  I agree with ianpgall about that.  If you checked every parameter of every function for exact correctness (which your code below does NOT!) then your code would perform horribly.  No one does this in any language.  Some level of knowledge of what you are calling is required.

Comment: @AresAvatar Not only do you not know if I down voted your post, according to the [documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down) a down vote on this post would be subjectively acceptable.

Comment: @anonymous, the likelihood of it having been you is quite high, and, I don't agree with you.

Comment: At the very least reasons were given why your post may have been down voted. My answer was down voted for no apparent reason.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16658/discussion-between-aresavatar-and-anonymous-down-voting-is-lame)

Comment: @anonymousdownvotingislame Checking inputs for validity is in no way best practice coding. Scratch that. You're NOT checking inputs for validity at all. You're checking for existence...which isn't necessary either. Most languages require you to explicitly define required parameters (and their types) and optional parameters. The fact that Javascript doesn't, leaves you with the option of adding incredible amounts of unnecessary checking, or allowing failure. Who are you creating the function for? You and your team...so if they don't know how to use it, they shouldn't use it at all.

Answer (score 1):

```
    function show_table(ids) {
        var idArr = ids.split(",");
        document.getElementById('table1').style.display='none';
      document.getElementById('table2').style.display='none';
      document.getElementById('table3').style.display='none';
      document.getElementById('table4').style.display='none';
      document.getElementById('table6').style.display='none';

        for(var i = 0; i< idArr.length; i++) {
            document.getElementById('table'+idArr[i]).style.display='block';
        }
    }

<a href="#" onclick="show_table('6,2')">
```

Comment: With this version you need to remember not to do this: show_table("6, 2") because the space would mess things up.

Comment: @anonymousdownvotingislame That's what you want. The code will bomb if incorrect input is given...SO DON'T GIVE INCORRECT INPUT.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer minimum force aproach, try this:

```
function hide_all_tables(){
    document.getElementById('table1').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('table2').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('table3').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('table4').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('table6').style.display='none';
}

function show_table(id){
    document.getElementById('table'+id).style.display='block';
}
```

And then use the code this way:

```
<a href="#" onclick="hide_all_tables();show_table(6);show_table(2);">Table6 and Table2</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never used a 'double onclick command' and to be honest don't think they work, or are good practice. Why don't you just house both show table comands in a javascript function and call the function onclick?

If i am understanding you correctly.

Comment: I think they meant two function calls in one onclick...which is what they're trying in their second snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You **can** change them all at once without looping, if the tables have logical associations (they must, right?).

The idea is to assign them a class (or multiple classes) and change the whole class at once:

```
<script>
function f(classname, show)
{
    var mysheet=document.styleSheets[0];

    /* Each class in the styleSheet is called a 'rule' */
    var myrules=mysheet.cssRules;

    var value = show ? '' : 'none'; /* show or hide? */
    for (i=0; i<myrules.length; i++){

        /* find the class we want to change */
        if(myrules[i].selectorText==classname){
            /* change the rule */
            myrules[i].style.display = value;
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style type="text/css" >
.hasPets { color: green; display: none; }
.hasCats { font-weight: bold; display: none; }
</style>

​<button onclick="f('.hasPets', true)">Show Pets</button>
​<button onclick="f('.hasCats', true)">Show Cats</button>
​<button onclick="f('.hasPets', false)">Hide Pets</button>
​<button onclick="f('.hasCats', false)">Hide Cats</button>

<div class="hasPets">Pets</div>
<div class="hasCats hasPets">Cats</div>
```

In this example, `Show Pets` shows both, `Hide Cats` hides only Cats. You can't show only Cats -- Pets overrides it.

**Note**: I've kept this short for clarity. In practice you'll have to add a few more lines because not all versions of IE support the `.cssRules property`, I think they called it `.rules`.

Answer (score -2):

This function allows for any number of tables to show.

```
function show_table(){
    for(var i = 1; i  < 7; i++) // change 7 to the amount of tables 
        if(document.getElementById('table'+i))
            document.getElementById('table'+i).style.display='none';

    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++)
        if(document.getElementById('table'+arguments[i]))
            document.getElementById('table'+arguments[i]).style.display='block';
}
```

To show tables with ids of `table3` and `table5` then:

```
show_table(3,5);
```

Comment: Even though *sshats down vote this answer with no comment or legitimate reason; I won't delete this answer. I think it's the best one here and I am eager to discuss why it others may not think so.